# Winform Ui still blocking because of textbox operation

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I am going to build a dictionary. Everything was fine. But there is a little problem. To stop blocking UI of my winform I run my long code inside a thread. As I know when I give our operation for a worker thread UI is not blocked. But when I run the project it is still blocking for milliseconds. I did a lot of thing to find out it. The issue is the code has a textbox

```cs
textBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)((() => textBox2.Text += aa[i].Trim() + Environment.NewLine + foundwords + Environment.NewLine+ Environment.NewLine)));
```

It blocks the UI for 200ms if I run the project for 2 seconds...
Here is the whole code inbutton click event

```cs
private void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    textBox2.Text = "";
    Thread btthread = new Thread(() => {
        foundwords = "";
        string words = "";
        textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() =>  words = textBox1.Text));
        string[] aa = words.Trim().Split('\n');

        for (int i = 0; i < aa.Length; i++)
        {
            string authors = DictionaryWords;
            foundwords = "";
            while (authors.Contains("\n"+aa[i].Trim().ToLower()+"\t"))
            {
                int index = authors.IndexOf("\n" + aa[i].Trim().ToLower() + "\t");// find where 1st hello is
                string sub = authors.Substring(index + ("\n" + aa[i].Trim().ToLower() + "\t").Length);// remove all before hello get string we named it sub
                int indexx = sub.IndexOf("\n"); // find \n index
                int final = index + ("\n" + aa[i].Trim().ToLower() + "\t").Length; // find the index after 1st hello
                string substr = authors.Substring(index + ("\n" + aa[i].Trim().ToLower() + "\t").Length, indexx); // select string after hello and before \n
                authors = sub.Substring(indexx);// remove all after
                foundwords += substr.Trim() + " ,";
            }
            textBox2.Invoke((MethodInvoker)((() => textBox2.Text += aa[i].Trim() + Environment.NewLine + foundwords + Environment.NewLine+ Environment.NewLine)));
        }
    });
    btthread.Start();
}
```

`DictionarywWords` is a big file which has meaning for sinhala language
I want to stop Blocking the UI. could somebody tell me , what I should do?

Comment: This is a firehose bug, the UI thread is burning 100% core trying to keep up with the Invoke() requests.  Use StringBuilder to collect a bunch of lines of text and only Invoke() once or a few times.

Answer (score 3):

forget threads and embrace `Tasks` and `async` `await`.

Put your long running code in an extra method that returns the data which be later used to fill the controls.

```
private WhatEverDataTypeSuitsYou CreateData()
{
    WhatEverDataTypeSuitsYou returnValue;

    // here goes your long running code
    return returnValue;
}
```

now you can make your click event handler also async and await the results in there. Since the method `createData` returns on the UI thread there will be no need for invokation. You can simply fill the controls with the data as you see fit

```
private async void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    var result = await Task.Run(CreateData);
    // now fill the controls without invoke
}
```

EDIT: Actually on the second glance at you code, I would suggest to use a [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-7.0) instead of concatenating strings. This is probably the reason why your code need so much time.

This particular line is the evil one:

```
foundwords += substr.Trim() + " ,";
```

Comment: sir should i return aa or ```foundwords ``` in 1st code you posted ?

Comment: @RyanGabriel "sir should i return aa" you are the only person how can reliably answer this question. Actually I showed you the structural approach. It is independent of the code that is being executed inside it. To be honest I did not read the loop and string operations. You have to decide in which form you want the data to be in the end.

Comment: The approach using tasks is the right one. But please don't start a Task using `Task.Run` inside an async method. Provide an async method as is and if the caller decides to forward that method call to its own task the caller will wrap the call using `Task.Run(CreateData)`. If async code calls async code and each method starts its own Task you'll run in a tremendous amount of Tasks that might lead in performance issues and makes debugging even harder.

Comment: @SebastianSchumann "Provide an async method as is" do you mean simply creating a task and returning it in the createData method? "if the caller decides to forward that method call to its own task the caller will wrap the call using Task.Run(CreateData)" that might make sense if you program an API that will be used by someone else, but in this practical example OP is the caller. I don't see it happening that they will "un in a tremendous amount of Tasks that might lead in performance issues and makes debugging even harder"

Comment: @SebastianSchumann "Provide an async method as is" could you provide an example? posting an alternative answer or even simply edit mine, I don't mind.

Comment: What I mean is: write an async method using async/wait without any `Task.Run` in its body. But yeah you're right - in that specific case OP will not have any issues.

Comment: Have a look at [here](https://www.pluralsight.com/guides/advanced-tips-using-task-run-async-wait): _Therefore, it's generally recommended that you put calls to Task.Run as close to the UI code and event handlers as possible._ It's all opinion based but code might be reused and maybe guidelines help a little.

Answer (score 0):

If I've understood what you're trying to do then I think I've got a solution that will run much much faster than your approach.

You are building a destroying many many strings in your search for the words that appear in the text `DictionaryWords`.

I gather that the file that `DictionaryWords` looks somewhat like this:

```
apple\ta fruit\n
Apple\ta computer\n
Banana\t\a fruit\n
fan\tone who follows a celebrity\n
Fan\ta device that moves air\n
```

NB: If you're on a PC then the line endings are `\r\n`, but I'll just assume you are on Linux.

A better data structure for working with this data would be this:

```
ILookup<string, string> dictionary =
    File
        .ReadLines(@"Path_to_DictionaryWords.txt")
        .Select(x => x.Split('\t'))
        .ToLookup(x => x[0].ToLower(), x => x[1]);
```

So, given my data above this would look like:

[image: dictionary]

Now if you take `textBox1` we can do this to get a list of words:

```
string[] words =
    textBox1
        .Text
        .ToLower()
        .Split(
            Environment.NewLine,
            StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
```

So if the user had entered this:

```
banana
apple
```

Then you'd have this:

[image: words]

Now, it's simple to get out the matching values:

```
string output =
    String.Join(
        Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine,
        from word in words
        where dictionary[word].Any()
        select $"{word}{Environment.NewLine}{String.Join(", ", dictionary[word])}");
```

That looks like:

```
banana
a fruit

apple
a fruit, a computer
```

That code will run much faster than yours and will produce the entire output in one go.

You may not need tasks or threads with this approach.

If you do, try this:

```
private async void button1_Click_2(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ILookup<string, string> dictionary = await Task.Run(() =>
        File
            .ReadLines(@"Path_to_DictionaryWords.txt")
            .Select(x => x.Split('\t'))
            .ToLookup(x => x[0].ToLower(), x => x[1]));
            
    string[] words =
        textBox1
            .Text
            .ToLower()
            .Split(
                Environment.NewLine,
                StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries | StringSplitOptions.TrimEntries);
    
    string output = await Task.Run(() =>
        String.Join(
            Environment.NewLine + Environment.NewLine,
            words.Select(w => $"{w}{Environment.NewLine}{String.Join(", ", dictionary[w])}")));

    textBox2.Text = output;
}
```